# Using Ajax dropdownextender and Bulletlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to work with **Ajax dropdownextender** and **Bulletlist**, this is my code in aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server"> 
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" OnClick="BulletedList_OnClick"></asp:BulletedList> 
</asp:Panel> 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="text"></asp:TextBox> 
<ajax:dropdownextender id="TextBox_DropDownExtender" runat="server" dynamicservicepath="" enabled="True" dropdowncontrolid="BulletedList1" targetcontrolid="TextBox1" ></ajax:dropdownextender> 
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and this is code in aspx.cs page

```
protected void BulletedList_OnClick(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Your have selected '" + BulletedList1.Items[e.Index].Text + "' as your preferred language";
}
```

but when I choose a Bulletlist item, Label1 is not written! 
Any tips? 
Thanks

Comment: is debugging working fine?

Comment: Void is not reached!

Comment: Try using `DisplayMode="LinkButton"`, e.g. `<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton" OnClick="BulletedList_OnClick">`

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this explanation in [BulletedList.OnClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler's 'remarks' section:

> The Click event is raised when a list item in the BulletedList control
>   is clicked. **To enable list items in a BulletedList control to raise
>   the Click event, you must first set the DisplayMode property to the
>   value LinkButton.**

Hence, your `BulletedList` control markup should use `DisplayMode` attribute to trigger click handler like this:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton" 
                  OnClick="BulletedList_OnClick">
</asp:BulletedList>
```